Unique solution to an equation involving convolution and probability densities
I am confronted with the following problem. Let $\overline{\mu}_s:=-\mu(x)1_{(-\infty,0)}(x)+\overline{\mu}(x)1_{(0,\infty)}(x)$ where $\mu$ is some cumulative distribution function and $\overline{\mu}=1-\mu$ its tail distribution function. Further let $\pi$ be some probability density function with full support on $\mathbb{R}$. Now I am interested in a solution $\nu\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ which is assumed to be a probability density as well that fulfills the following equation $$\big(\overline{\mu}_s\star\pi(x)\big) \cdot \nu(x) = \big(\overline{\mu}_s\star\nu(x)\big) \cdot \pi(x),$$
for almost every $x\in\mathbb{R}$ where $\mu_s\star f(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \overline{\mu}_s(u)f(x-u)d u$ is the usual convolution of functions.
Clearly $\nu=\pi$ solves this. But is there another probability density function that can solve this equation? I am not particularly interested in obtaining a solution, but only to answer the question of uniqueness. Except for some asymptotic tail behaviour the choice of $\mu$ is free.
In short: is there a choice of $\mu$ and, if necessary, on $\pi$ s.t. the only solution to this equation among probability densities is $\pi$?
Any hints, also w.r.t. literature and methods to tackle this, are greatly appreciated.
